# How to have UITextField allow only integers And Maximum 10 digit with Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

How to have UITextField allow only integers And Maximum 10 digit. Can Anyone Help Me.

Hear Is My Code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else {
        return false
    }
    let LettersOnly = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    let updateText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
    phonecounter.text = "\(10 - updateText.count)"
    updateText.count < 13 || LettersOnly.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
}
```

In textfield enter only 10 integer with label count.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to check for non-digit characters and if the `location` of the range < 10

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil && range.location < 10
}
```

It can be still simpler be specifying the Number Keypad, then checking the length is sufficient,